# How to add relation types defined in WKS to Watson discovery

Tags: watson-discovery, watson-knowledge-studio

I have created a model in WKS that contains relations_types along with entity_types.
I want to deploy this model to Discovery now. However while creating the custom configuration I donot see the option for adding realtion_types.

Hence when I download the Json copy of the of the discovery configuration to add the model_id of WKS, I can find the Entity_types but I cannot find relation types.

Does this mean Discovery does not support relation types?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add as "features" in your custom configuration any feature available for the natural language understanding.
For instance, to extract relations you can have:

```
 "features": {
    "relations": {}
  }
```

See all the options in the [NLU reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#relations)